# Плавное появление элемента из display:none в inline

Tags: html, jquery, css, transform, display

Интересует такая штука – как заставить блок расширяться плавно при наведении, то есть иконка становится видимой по мере того, как в течение анимации до конца выезжает кнопка справа?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 100px;
}

.cat-block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cat-block .category {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 0px rgba(1, 2, 4, 0.25);
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .2s ease-out;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.cat-block .category img {
  width: 13px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: none;
}


.cat-block .category:hover img {
  display: inline;
}

.cat-block .category a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.cat-block .category:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 0px rgba(1, 2, 4, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.cat-block .category:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.cat-block .category:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  padding-left: 14px;

}

.cat-block .category:nth-of-type(4) {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<center>
<div class="cat-block">
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#первый</a></div>
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#последующий</a></div>
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#следующий за ним</a></div>
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#последний</a></div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andrey-fedorov прав, сделать плавность с помощью css/display:none невозможно, это можно сделать при помощи jQuery например. А вот если изменять ширину от 0 до заданной, то с помощью css это сделать можно вот так:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 100px;
}

.cat-block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cat-block .category {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 0px rgba(1, 2, 4, 0.25);
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .2s ease-out;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.cat-block .category img {
  width: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
  transition: .3s;
}


.cat-block .category:hover img {
  width:13px
}

.cat-block .category a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.cat-block .category:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 0px rgba(1, 2, 4, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.cat-block .category:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.cat-block .category:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  padding-left: 14px;

}

.cat-block .category:nth-of-type(4) {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<center>
<div class="cat-block">
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#первый</a></div>
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#последующий</a></div>
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#следующий за ним</a></div>
<div class="category"><img src="http://payjay.ru/img/icons/letter.png"><a href="#">#последний</a></div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Важно понимать, что есть свойства, которые не анимируются через `transition`. Прежде всего это свойства со значениями в виде текста, например `display: none`. С другой стороны, свойства имеющие численные значения, например, `opacity: 1` являются анимируемыми.

Исходя из этого вам нужно так переделать свой код, чтобы появление иконки было задано анимируемыми свойствами. Например можно задать отрицательный `margin-left`, а по наведению мыши задавать ему нулевое значение. Тогда иконка будет как бы выезжать слева.

Надеюсь принцип понятен?